# How to add multiple items into a column SQLite3?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sqlite

I don't want to use different python packages like pickle.
I also don't want to use multiple databases.

So, how do I add a list or a tuple into a column of a database?

I had a theory of adding a string that would be like `'(val1, val2, val3)'` and then use `exec` to put it into a variable but that is too far-fetched and there is definitely a better and more efficient way of doing this.

EDIT:
I'll add some more information on what I'm looking for.

I want to get (and add) lists with this type of info:

`{'pet':'name','type':'breed/species_of_pet', 'img':img_url, 'hunger':'100'}`
I want this dict to be in the `pets` column.
Each pet can have many owners (many-to-many relationship)

Comment: Does each pet have one owner or multiple?

Comment: Multiple owners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a users table and each user can have pets. You'd first make a pets table.

```
create table pets (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null,
  hunger int not null default 0
);
```

Then it depends on whether a pet has only one owner (known as a one-to-many relationship) or many owners (known as a many-to-many relationship).

---

If a pet has one owner, then add a column with the user ID to the pets table. This is a [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

```
create table pets (
  id integer primary key,
  -- When a user is deleted, their pet's user_id will be set to null.
  user_id integer references users(id) on delete set null,
  name text not null,
  hunger int not null default 0
);
```

To get all the pets of one user...

```
select pets.*
from pets
where user_id = ?
```

To get the name of the owner of a pet we do a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) matching each rows of pets with their owner's rows using `pets.user_id` and `users.id`.

```
select users.name
from users
join pets on pets.user_id = users.id
where pets.id = ?
```

---

If each pet can have many owners, a many-to-many relationship, we don't put the user_id into pets. Instead we need an extra table: a join table.

```
create table pet_owners (
  -- When a user or pet is deleted, delete the rows relating them.
  pet_id integer not null references pets(id) on delete cascade,
  user_id integer not null references users(id) on delete cascade
);
```

We declare that a user owns a pet by inserting into this table.

```
-- Pet 5 is owned by users 23 and 42.
insert into pet_owners (pet_id, user_id) values (5, 23), (5, 42);
```

To find a user's pets and their name, we query pet_owners and join with pets to get the name.

```
select pets.*
from pet_owners
join pets on pet_owners.pet_id = pets.id
where user_id = ?
```

---

This might seem weird and awkward, and it is, but it's why SQL databases are so powerful and fast. It's done to avoid having to do any parsing or interpretation of what's in the database. This allows the database to efficiently query data using [indexes](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) rather than having to sift through all the data. This makes even very large databases efficient.

When you query `select pets.* from pets where user_id = ?`, because foreign keys are indexed, SQLite does not search the entire pets table. It uses the index on user_id to jump straight to the matching records. This means the database will perform the same with 10 or 10 million pets.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't really want to make more tables in the database. Is there any way I could do it without having multiple tables?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes, you could cram tuples and dicts in as strings, but it will be slow and buggy and require a lot of extra code. SQL is for relational databases, and you want a relationship between pets and their owners. The alternative is a [NoSQL database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) or a JSON column in MySQL or [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html). However, these are not a good fit for your problem. There's a very good reason we've been using SQL for 50 years and will continue. It's worth it.

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate this into a discord bot. So for `references` as you did up there, could i do `references users(id) and users(guild_id)`?

Comment: Also, isn't `create pet_owners` supposed to be `create table pet_owners`?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes, it should be `create table pet_owners`. You only need to reference the primary key of a table, there's no need to reference additional columns. What are you trying to do by referencing `users(guild_id)`?

Comment: I assumed that `references` passed the value onto both tables based on the column name passed. So, I thought it would pass guild_id onto both tables.

Comment: @12944qwerty Nothing is being passed between tables. It's used for "referential integrity" to ensure you cannot refer to things which do not exist. `user_id references users(id)` means that if you insert or update `pet_owners.user_id` to 42 there *must* be a row in users whose id is 42. `on delete cascade` says when user 42 is deleted, all pet_owners rows who have user_id 42 will automatically be deleted; you won't have stale join table rows pointing to deleted users and pets. Referential integrity is a key advantage of SQL databases.

Comment: Ok. That clears things up a lot more. Thank you!
However, I only want to delete the ones where if `user_id` 42 and `guild_id` is the same as the one that got deleted, then `on delete cascade` will start...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216022/discussion-between-schwern-and-12944qwerty).

Comment: Hey Schwern. I noticed that you left the chat discussion. I had something I wanted you to see there still. So can you please check it, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from storing JSON or other array-like text in SQLite; it's just that it's much harder to query when you do so.  SQLite does have [facilities for manipulating JSON](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), but in general I would probably lean toward @Schwern's solution.